# Delphi XE3 - Copying data from a TBytesField to another TBytesField

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a ADO dataset (DataSet1) with TBytesField and the DataSize of the field is 12.

I want to copy the TBytesField data to another DataSet having a TBytesField with DataSize 12.

I used the given below line of code to copy the field value from DataSet1 to DataSet2:

```
DataSet2.Fields[0].Value := DataSet1.Fields[0].Value.
```

This code was working in Delphi 2009, but after migrating to Delphi XE3, this is not working anymore. It raises an error *"Invalid variant type"* while trying to set the value.
I tried to use `GetData` and `SetData` but the same error is raised.

I think there is a bug with Delphi XE3 ADODB code while setting the data.

Anybody experienced this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried to use Assign: `DataSet2.Fields[0].Assign(DataSet1.Fields[0]);` ?

Comment: Looking at the source code for `TBinaryField`, which is the ancestor of `TBytesField`, I think you have to try using the `.AsBytes` property, like this: `DataSet2.Fields[0].AsBytes := DataSet1.Fields[0].AsBytes;`. I'm not totally sure, so I post this as a comment, if you confirm it works I'll write an answer.

Comment: Embarcadero released buggy and breaking changes with COM/OLE and variants in XE2 Update 4. What is VarType for the ds1 f0 value ? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Variants.VarType

Comment: @jachguate, I tried using assign and AsBytes before itself. But same error raises. Then I debugged into the ADODB and I am sure there is a problem with the size in that code. If I set my TBytesField size to 16, then it works.